# executing the make config shared=1 command for METIS in python 2.7 on my windows 7 machine

Tags: python, variables, environment

I have a new issue. I have successfully installed Metis 0.1 but I'm not able to execute the `make config shared=1` command. Additionally, I do not know where I have to execute this command.
Should I execute it on command prompt? Or should I execute this line on the python prompt? Or is this done in some other way? How do I do this? can anyone explain it in detail. I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Based on just the documentation and having never used METIS, it seems that you'd use this when compiling METIS from source. I understood that the Python library needs METIS to be built with this "shared" flag on to work.

Comment: You would need to use Visual Studios to do this and I am not sure how to ask Visual Studios to add that flag, but what you can do is just change the line in the CMakeLists such that it creates the shared folder. Consider what I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675790/how-to-install-metis-package-in-python-on-windows/56998495#56998495) on installing METIS on windows for how I was able to generate a DLL file.