# how to install METIS library for python?

Tags: python, installation, metis

I want to install METIS for python on windows7.i use:

```
pip install metis
```

I got this result:

```
Requirement already satisfied: metis in 
c:\users\mina\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages 
(0.2a4)
```

and I used the following code:

```
make config shared=1
```

I got this result:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `config'.  Stop.
```

Maybe you can help me.

Comment: If anyone is still struggling with this issue on Windows, they should consider my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675790/how-to-install-metis-package-in-python-on-windows/56998495#56998495).

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install metis
      -or-
easy_install metis
```

You might need to add "shared=1" to your config options when building Metis from source so it builds a shared library instead of a static one.

Note that the shared library is needed, and isn’t enabled by default by the configuration process. Turn it on by issuing:

```
make config shared=1
make install
```

Then, set up your METIS_DLL environment variable:

```
export METIS_DLL=/usr/local/lib/libmetis.dylib
```

Source: https://metis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Your `makefile` should ideally be named `makefile`, not `make`. Note that you can call your `makefile` anything you like, but as you found, you then need the `-f` option with make to specify the name of the `makefile`. Using the default name of `makefile` just makes life easier.

Comment: I do not know what to do now. exactly what should I do?

Comment: insted of `make` you can try using `makefile` once..!!

Comment: @SurajM I run into the same issue. i seems that its unclear where we should run "make config shared=1" and the following commands. pip seems to actually install the package to "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/" However, there's no makefile in the metis folder. should I make a new one? also, there's no libmeis.dylib in "/usr/local/lib/"

Answer (score 1):

The metis-python is just a wrapper, it does not have the core METIS yet, you need to install METIS separately. You can get the source from here:

> http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/download

the installation instruction can be found inside the package at Install.txt. Once you download and unpack it, Suraj M's answer above will come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to note that when I install python metis on Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

After you `make install`, you may only get `libmetis.so` in the `/usr/local/lib` directory.

Therefore

> `export METIS_DLL=/usr/local/lib/libmetis.dylib`

should be changed to

> `export METIS_DLL=/usr/local/lib/libmetis.so`

Answer (score 0):

By doing this, I would have been able to resolve the problem and run my code seamlessly.

```
import requests
import tarfile

# Download and extract the file
url = "http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/fetch/sw/metis/metis-5.1.0.tar.gz"
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
file = tarfile.open(fileobj=response.raw, mode="r|gz")
file.extractall(path=".")

# Change working directory
%cd metis-5.1.0

# The remaining steps as you have shown in the question, with updated path
!make config shared=1 prefix=~/.local/
!make install
!cp ~/.local/lib/libmetis.so /usr/lib/libmetis.so
!export METIS_DLL=/usr/lib/libmetis.so
!pip3 install metis-python
```